# Save static GIF as JPG

Tags: python-3.x, gif, python-imaging-library

Given a GIF, I'd like to detect if it is static, and if so, save it as a JPG. How can this be done?

I only know that if `EOFError` occurs on `Image.seek(1)` then it's static. But once I have the frame, how do I save it? If I try to save it using `Image.save('test.jpg', 'JPEG')`, I get an error:

`OSError: cannot write mode P as JPEG`

Ideally, I'd like to find a simple one or two-liner solution to this.

Comment: You'd need to do `img = img.convert("RGB")` first.

Comment: @jasonharper that works perfectly, thanks. If you want to make that into an Answer, I'll mark it as accepted